# Ошибка создания базы данных rails в продакшене

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

На сервере пытаюсь создать базу данных, но там меня поджидал небольшой "сюрприз", который я пытаюсь разрешить уже достаточное количество времени. Ниже прилагаю саму ошибку и частично `Gemfile`. Не знаю, что с этим делать, даже в какую сторону, хотя бы, двигаться

```
   $ bundle exec rails db:create RAILS_ENV=production 
        rails aborted!
        LoadError: Error loading the 'postgresql' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.
        bin/rails:9:in `<main>'

        Caused by:
        Gem::LoadError: pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.
        bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
        Tasks: TOP => db:create => db:load_config
        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Gemfile (гемы ставил через `bundle install --without test development`)

```
    # Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
    gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'

    group :production do
      gem 'pg'
    end
```

Comment: А зачем в гемфайле `pg` указан два раза - в общем списке и отдельно для прода? Оставьте один, в общем списке. `bundle install` прошёл без ошибок?

Comment: @Василиса оставил один в общем списке, гемы ставятся без ошибок, но бд по-прежнему не создается

Comment: Какая версии `pg` сейчас на сервере (`gem list | grep pg`)? . Ошибка та же осталась? Я бы попробовала заново всё поставить с исправленным гемфайлом

Comment: @Василиса, pg (1.1.4) стоит. Ошибка не изменилась. А заново поставить в каком плане? Удалить директорию с проектом и заново его поставить?

Comment: А вы где проект деплоите и чем пользуетесь для этого? Что у вас в database.yml? Все ли ENV переменные на сервере есть?

Comment: `bundle exec rails db:create RAILS_ENV=production `

Comment: @Nakilon, все равно ошибка

Comment: @Василиса, деплою на Ubuntu 18.04. Вот содержимое [database.yml](https://pastebin.com/U7zyACn9). По поводу ENV переменных не совсем понял, может и есть

Comment: Я имела в виду, пользуете ли вы ansible, capistrano и всякие другие удобные вещи. Тогда проще было бы поднять сервер с нуля и начать всё заново с правильным гемфайлом. А если через rake? `bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production --trace` И добавьте лог к вопросу

Comment: @Василиса, Capistrano не использовал. Вот [лог](https://pastebin.com/FE3ENJRq). Ansible тоже пока не пользуюсь, так как не освоил до конца эту технологию и не в состоянии её применять. Вообще, деплоем я занимаюсь по [этому](https://youtu.be/aJLRnDJ2CVg) курсу, никакие шаги не пропускал

Comment: Видеокурсы - это хорошо, но найти среди кадров гемфайл (например) нереально :( Попробуйте ещё кэш бутснапа грохнуть (tmp/cache/bootsnap*). Кстати, в видео же 5-е рельсы, а у вас 6-е. Может быть, в этом дело. Я вижу один вариант - убить этот сервер и начать всё заново, соблюдая все версии из видео (я сейчас именно про рельсы, а не про всякие линуксовые вещи)